# "Cant play video" error in VideoView after reading the uri from database

Tags: android, database, uri

In my app, I am selecting videos using Intent as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);
```

Then the uri of the video is saved in the database in String format

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
        Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
        if (selectedVideoUri != null) {
                    videoPathList.add(selectedVideoUri.toString());
```

I read the string from the database, convert it to uri using Uri.parse() method and use it to play the video. However I get "Cant play video" error.

```
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    //Creating MediaController
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri uri= Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("video_path"));

    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

The video plays fine if I play using the uri obtained in onActivityResult(). The problem occurs only after saving the uri to the database in string format. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Then the uri of the video is saved in the database in String format

The `Uri` may not be usable later on.

> How do I solve this?

On Android 4.4+, switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Then, when you get your `Uri`, call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver`. This should give you durable access to the content identified by the `Uri`, and you should be able to play back the video later... assuming that the video is still there, of course.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more on this subject.

Comment: I need the video uri's for a longer duration. I should be able to play the videos even after quit and launch of the app. Hence I am storing them in the database so that I can retrieve them at a later point in time.

Comment: @SahanaKamath: And that is fine, if you follow the instructions in my answer.